# Android Kotlin how to check checkbox in multiple choice list view

Tags: android, kotlin, android-checkbox

I have a multiple choice list view. I wanting to check some of the checkboxes but not all of them. I am trying the code below but not sure where to go from there, or if that is even a start.

```
val listView = findViewById<ListView>(R.id.mylist_listview)
        val values = arrayOf("One", "Two", "Three")

        val list = ArrayList<String>()
        for (i in values.indices) {
            list.add(values[i])
        }
        val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, list)
        listView.setAdapter(adapter)


        val cntChoice = listView.getCount()

        for (i in 0 until cntChoice) {

            listView. //Something to check boxes 

            }

        }
```

Comment: Found setItemChecked() method. It works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use multiple choice add `listView.choiceMode = ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE`

and to check items you need to use `listView.setItemChecked(position, true)`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

```
  for (i in 0 until cntChoice) {
        listView.setItemChecked(i,true)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Kotlin: Multiple choice checkbox checked & add in list And Unchecked checkbox then remove in same list of element**

*I hope your checkbox in static form: like you knowing fixed checkbox on my UI then this code used*

**add code in your class file**

```
private var socialList: String? = null
private var socialMArray = ArrayList<String>()
private var chkArraySocial = arrayOfNulls<CheckBox>(7)

private var strFaceBook: String? = null
private var strTwitter: String? = null
private var strInstagram: String? = null
private var strWhatsApp: String? = null
private var strSnapChat: String? = null
private var strLinkedIn: String? = null
private var strOtherSocial: String? = null
private var regex = "\\[|\\]"

/** social media list **/
    strTwitter = getResStringLanguage(R.string.str_twitter, "en")
    strInstagram = getResStringLanguage(R.string.str_instagram, "en")
    strFaceBook = getResStringLanguage(R.string.str_facebook, "en")
    strWhatsApp = getResStringLanguage(R.string.str_whatsapp, "en")
    strLinkedIn = getResStringLanguage(R.string.str_linkedin, "en")
    strSnapChat = getResStringLanguage(R.string.str_snapchat, "en")
    strOtherSocial = getResStringLanguage(R.string.str_other, "en")

    chkArraySocial[0] = binding.cbFbSocial
    chkArraySocial[0]?.text = strFaceBook
    chkArraySocial[0]?.setOnCheckedChangeListener(clickListSocial)
    chkArraySocial[1] = binding.cbTwitterSocial
    chkArraySocial[1]?.text = strTwitter
    chkArraySocial[1]?.setOnCheckedChangeListener(clickListSocial)
    chkArraySocial[2] = binding.cbInstagramSocial
    chkArraySocial[2]?.text = strInstagram
    chkArraySocial[2]?.setOnCheckedChangeListener(clickListSocial)
    chkArraySocial[3] = binding.cbWhatsappSocial
    chkArraySocial[3]?.text = strWhatsApp
    chkArraySocial[3]?.setOnCheckedChangeListener(clickListSocial)
    chkArraySocial[4] = binding.cbLinkedinSocial
    chkArraySocial[4]?.text = strLinkedIn
    chkArraySocial[4]?.setOnCheckedChangeListener(clickListSocial)
    chkArraySocial[5] = binding.cbSnapchatSocial
    chkArraySocial[5]?.text = strSnapChat
    chkArraySocial[5]?.setOnCheckedChangeListener(clickListSocial)
    chkArraySocial[6] = binding.cbOtherSocial
    chkArraySocial[6]?.text = strOtherSocial
    chkArraySocial[6]?.setOnCheckedChangeListener(clickListSocial)

private val clickListSocial: CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener = CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
    val checkedId: Int = buttonView?.id!!
    for (i in chkArraySocial.indices) {
        val current = chkArraySocial[i]
        if (current?.id == checkedId) {
            val checkBoxSocial = view?.findViewById<CheckBox>(current.id)
            val cbValueSocial = checkBoxSocial?.text.toString()
            if (isChecked){
                socialMArray.add(cbValueSocial)
                val formattedDirections = socialMArray.toString().trim().replace("\\.\\s?".toRegex(), "\\.\n")
                socialList = formattedDirections.replace(regex.toRegex(),"")
                Log.i("TAG", "social media add list: $socialList")
            }else{
                socialMArray.remove(cbValueSocial)
                val formattedDirections = socialMArray.toString().trim().replace("\\.\\s?".toRegex(), "\\.\n")
                socialList = formattedDirections.replace(regex.toRegex(),"")
                Log.i("TAG", "social media remove list: $socialList")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**language change on select checkbox value**

```
fun getResStringLanguage(id: Int, lang: String?): String {
    val res = resources
    val conf = res.configuration
    val savedLocale = conf?.locale
    val confAr = resources.configuration
    confAr?.locale = Locale(lang!!)
    val metrics = DisplayMetrics()
    val resources = Resources(resources.assets, metrics, confAr)
    val string = resources.getString(id)
    conf?.locale = savedLocale
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, null)
    return string
}
```